# What is the best feature selection method when working with audio and a binary output?

Tags: audio, classification

I am working on a problem as I am trying to determine which is the best feature to use when working with audio.  I have a piece of audio and I am trying to determine which is the best feature to use when detecting a clap.  I am extracting multiple features such as spectral centroid, spectral flux etc and and I want to compare them to my labelled data. My output is binary which means that either there is a clap or there isn't.  They are represented buy either a 0 or a 1.  My feature data is continuous. I have made a diagram to show better what I am trying to explain. I need a mathematical proof that Feature A ranks better than Feature B.
[image]

Comment: What is the non-clap data?  There is a whole universe of sounds.  Just because the peak here is taller doesn't mean it is better.  I could just multiply the Centroid by 2.  You need to measure separation between claps and other sounds.

Comment: @IanJ The other sound is background noise.  I am not interested in classifying that data all that I am interested in is the detection of the clap.

Comment: I guess you missed the point of IanJ's question: It is important to know what the background is. If the background is wind blowing through trees, it might be easier to detect the clapping than if the background was horses running on a street.

Comment: @M529 Thank you for your comment.  No the background is almost silence.